# GridSizer is not placing my elements correctly

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxgrid

what im trying to do is make a 4X3 Gridsizer and attach my object on each spot but when I run it , it appears to run fine but everything is smooshed to the left side. I don't see what im doing wrong Below is the code for that section of my program

```
class F_WaferMaps ( wx.Frame ):

def __init__( self, parent, dateBegin , dateEnd):
    wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 800,500 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
    self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
    gSizer1 = wx.GridSizer( 4, 3, 3,3 )

    waferDesign = WaferInfo(die_size = (.3,.45),center_xy= (10 ,6.5), dia= 6.0 , edge_excl= 0.0 )
    waferInfo = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", index_col= None, na_values=['NA'] , usecols=[18,4,5,21,2])
    df2 = waferInfo[(waferInfo.FILE_FINISH_TS >= dateBegin) & (waferInfo.FILE_FINISH_TS <= dateEnd) ]
    waferSubSet = df2[['X', 'Y' , 'HB', 'TIME' , 'LOT']]
    df3 = waferSubSet[~(waferSubSet[['X_COORD', 'Y_COORD', 'LOT_WF']].duplicated(keep = 'last'))] 
    a = 0
    self.hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    waferNum = 0 
    for lotID, wafNum in df3.groupby(['LOT_WF']):
        df4 = wafNum[['X_COORD', 'Y_COORD', 'HB_NUM']]
        print(wafNum)
        print("\n")
        my_list = df4.transform(tuple, axis=1).tolist()
        self.panels = wm_core.WaferMapPanel(self, my_list, waferDesign, data_type='discrete'.lower())
        gSizer1.Add(self.panels,1)
        waferNum += 1
    self.SetSizer( gSizer1 )
    self.Layout()

    self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
```

so I want my output to look like

```
A B C 
D E F
G H I
J K M
```

but instead im getting something like

```
A
B
C
D
E
etc
```

Below is the class of the WaferMapApp like requested in the comments

```
def _init_ui(self):

    """Create the UI Elements and bind various events."""

    # Create items to add to our layout

    self.canvas = FloatCanvas.FloatCanvas(self,

                                          BackgroundColor="BLACK",

                                          )



    # Initialize the FloatCanvas. Needs to come before adding items!
    self.canvas.InitAll()
    # Create the legend

    self._create_legend()
    # Draw the die and wafer objects (outline, crosshairs, etc) on the canvas

    self.draw_die()

    if self.plot_die_centers:

        self.draw_die_center()

    self.draw_wafer_objects()

    # Bind events to the canvas

    self._bind_events()

    # Create layout manager and add items

    self.hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.hbox.Add(self.legend, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.hbox.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(self.hbox)
```

im not sure if is the layout of this that is causing the issue

Comment: did you look at the sample code in C++/wxPython demo code?

Comment: yup that's kind of how I did this one

Comment: @JeffPermia, is hbox or vbox being used anywhere? Also, is it the whole code?

Comment: no sorry that was something else I was trying but yes that is the whole code for that frame

Comment: Does `WaferMapPanel` specify fixed position? It should use `wx.DefaultPosition`

Comment: no 'WaferMapPanel' is not the position , it's creates a wafer

Comment: I'm asking about the control (panel, textbox, or whatever) that's added to the GridSizer.

Comment: oh okay sorry , so the line gSizer1.Add(self.panels,1) basically is supposed to put the PANELS in the grid one by one

Comment: Yes, I know. Again, when you construct each PANEL, before adding it the sizer, do you use default position? Better post the code for that `WaferMapPanel` class.

Comment: That im not too sure off since im using an imported library called wafer_map but I think I found what youre asking for , I read through his class on GitHub and this is what I found 
        self.hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)



        self.hbox.Add(self.legend, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.hbox.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.EXPAND)



        self.SetSizer(self.hbox)

Comment: I went ahead and posted the code on my edit